# processing multipart/form-data

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, file-upload

I'm doing file upload using `XMLHttpRequest()` in my jsp and when I do request.getContentType() in my controller I'm getting:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4664151417711.
```

Further I'm not getting how to get the file and get the contents of it in my controller. Please anyone help.

Update -- 
I'm doing this in my jsp.

```
 function fileUpload() {
var url= document.getElementById("urlId").value;
 var file= document.getElementById("xslId").files[0];
 var formdata = new FormData();
 formdata.append("url", url);
 formdata.append("file", file);
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
 xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/XlsUpload/openSource.htm", true);
 xhr.send(formdata);
 xhr.onload = function(e) {
    };                    
   }
```

and in my controller--

```
 public void openSource(@ModelAttribute("domTool") DomTool   domTool,HttpServletRequest     request,HttpServletResponse response){
     String type=request.getContentType();
```

Further I'm struck how to get the contents of the uploaded file and the value of text field i.e.,URL in my controller. The type i'm getting as multipart/form-data

Comment: Consider adding additional information. By adding code snippet you would let people know what your code does. In current form it is difficult to guess whats wrong.

Comment: Just by looking at the tags, I can imagine that you're trying to upload a file using an ajax request. You can't do this inside an ajax request for security reasons, it would be better to use a component that already handles ajax interaction by you like [blueImp  jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) (it uses an iframe to handle the *ajax request*).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza HTML5 supports this already. Although, it would not be available in all the browsers.

Comment: @Ck- that's the job of libraries like the one I've post in my link: leverage the interaction with the browser that supports (or not) the ajax file upload and facilitate the job for programmers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ah ok I get it  now. I am aware about blueImp. From first glance at your previous comment I thought you mean we cannot do it in plain vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Are you testing this in IE? Because it will never work there.

Comment: No Sir.I'm testing it in Firefox

Comment: Are you using a HTML5 page? Otherwise you can't upload the file by ajax request.

Comment: No Sir. Please help me.Is there any alternate way to accomplish this? If so please help me with a sample of code or some guide.

Comment: Check the link posted in my comment. Also, please do not refer to me as sir (I feel too young to be treated like that =) ). To send a comment to a person, use `@` and the IGN i.e. `@LuiggiMendoza` or `@Ck-`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Apache commons solution called `commons-fileupload` for parsing multipart content. You can find it [here](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

The most simple example copied from their [tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) looks like this:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List items = upload.parseRequest(request);

    // iterate over items (i.e. list of FileItem) and access 
    // the content with getInputStream()
}
```

Comment: i think he want to do this in JS

Comment: @kromit it does not make any sence... why would he then speak about upload, jsp and controller?